# Run all unittests from seperate py file

Tags: python, selenium, unit-testing

I have multiple py files with unit tests specified for specific module.

I want to import these unittests to seperate py file and run them from there, but I have trouble getting it working.

example of one of the unittest:

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from to_import import acceptConsent, URL_poznavacky, URL_poznavacky_vikendy, URL_poznavacky_rodiny, URL_pobocky
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import unittest

class TestPobocky_D(unittest.TestCase):
    def setup_method(self, method):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
        self.vars = {}

    def teardown_method(self, method):
        self.driver.quit()


    def test_pobocky_D(self):
        self.driver.get(URL_pobocky)
        acceptConsent(self.driver)
        self.driver.maximize_window()
        time.sleep(2)
        mapa = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='leaflet-pane leaflet-tile-pane']")    ## jen jeden element, no need to call find_elementS

        mapaDisplayed = mapa.is_displayed()
        assert mapaDisplayed == True


        mapaKolecka = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='leaflet-marker-icon marker-cluster marker-cluster-medium leaflet-zoom-animated leaflet-interactive']")
        y=0
        for _ in mapaKolecka:
            mapaKoleckaDisplayed = mapaKolecka[y].is_displayed()

            y=y+1
            print("mapa kolecka")
            assert mapaKoleckaDisplayed == True


        pobockaBoxiky = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='f_branch-header f_anchor']")
        x=0
        for _ in pobockaBoxiky:
            pobockaBoxikyDisplay = pobockaBoxiky[x].is_displayed()

            print("boxiky")
            assert pobockaBoxikyDisplay == True
            x=x+1

        basicInfo = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='f_branch-basicInfo']")
        a=0
        for _ in basicInfo:
            basicInfoDisplay = basicInfo[a].is_displayed()

            print("basic info ")
            assert basicInfoDisplay == True
            a=a+1
```

I want to import the whole class TestPobocky_D to new file and run it in seperate py file. I tried following:

```
import unittest
from pobocky import TestPobocky_D

TestPobocky_D(unittest.TestCase)
```

that just gives me this error

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/KDK/Desktop/Automation_Local_Deploy_PyCharm/starter_local.py", line 4, in <module>
    TestPobocky_D(unittest.TestCase)
  File "C:\Users\KDK\anaconda3\lib\unittest\case.py", line 433, in __init__
    testMethod = getattr(self, methodName)
TypeError: getattr(): attribute name must be string"
```

Anyone who can help me with this please ? Or point me to the right direction how to go about this.

Thanks in advance for every response

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace of the error?

Comment: sure
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/KDK/Desktop/Automation_Local_Deploy_PyCharm/starter_local.py", line 4, in <module>
    TestPobocky_D(unittest.TestCase)
  File "C:\Users\KDK\anaconda3\lib\unittest\case.py", line 433, in __init__
    testMethod = getattr(self, methodName)
TypeError: getattr(): attribute name must be string

Comment: What do you expect `TestPobocky_D(unittest.TestCase)` to do? You're creating an instance of the `TestPobocky_D` class, passing the `unittest.TestCase` class to its `__init__` function. I don't think that makes sense

Comment: Have a read of https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#organizing-test-code and specifically "However, should you want to customize the building of your test suite, you can do it yourself:". That said, it's not clear to me why you are trying to run the unit tests this way, rather than using a test runner such as that built into unittest, or pytest etc.

Comment: I expect it to run the test_pobocky_D (or all of the tests included in the class if there is more)

Comment: Alright I read through it and im progressing :) thanks for pointing the way for me

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try as below?

### starttest.py

```
import unittest
from pobocky import TestPobocky_D
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(argv=[''],verbosity=2, exit=False)
```

Run the command "python -m unittest starttest.py"

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response - I get following error
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\KDK\Desktop\Automation_Local_Deploy_PyCharm\pobocky.py", line 18, in test_pobocky_D
    self.driver.get(URL_pobocky)
AttributeError: 'TestPobocky_D' object has no attribute 'driver'"

prolly because the driver is defined in the setup metod, any idea how to go around it?
I tried creating suite as well and there is the same problem, if I go and define driver inside the test_pobocky it works but I would prefer leaving the setup metod as it is. any ideas? Thanks!